# Taking knockback backwards

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Would you be able to make a mob or person take knockback backwards? As in, if you shot someone that was running, they would take knockback backwards? (Tyring to make a harpoon gun with bow)

Comment: You mean similar to the effect of a fishing rod. When a mob or player is hooked, you can "reel" them in a few feet. Is this what you're saying?

Comment: What do you mean: in a normal game / in a mod / in command blocks?

Answer (score -1):

Make a command like this:

```
{display:{Name:"Test Name"},ench:[{id:19,lvl:1}]}
```

It  will give you a Item with the name "Test Name" with **knockback** 1.

You use this:

```
ench[{id:(enchantment_id,lvl:enchantment_level)}]
```

like that for enchantments. For names, use this:

```
display:{Name="Name of item"}
```

Remember to use curly brackets and colons inbetweeen.